# UISegmentedControl Problem setting hidden

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi I regulary created using IB one UISegmentedControl that I called showAllSwitch.
If I try to do `[showAllSwitch setHidden:YES];` nothing happens!
Why? How can I do to hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding an object is relatively straight forward.  So if there is a problem then its something simple.  You need to just go through some basic diagnostic steps:

1. Verify that your segmented control is actually connected to the correct outlet in IB.  Really. Go look.  Even if you are sure.  Go look again.
2. Verify that the line where you are hiding it is being called.  Add an NSLog just after and see if it shows up when it should.
3. Make sure that the hide command is not getting sent too soon.  If its being sent in ViewDidLoad try setting it up in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: The switch is inside a toolbar... Is this important?

Comment: not sure.  Haven't worked with toolbars a lot.  Can you do other things with the control like changing the number of segments, or the color etc.?  That would at least tell if you are able to communicate with it.

Comment: Take a look at the apple documentation for UIToolbar and see how it handles its buttons.  You might have to remove the control from the toolbar instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling setHidden? if it is being called before it is added to the view, then there could be problems. Try calling it in viewDidAppear and see it that works. If it doesn't either the segmentedControl is not connected correctly in IB, or there is a rather big problem that we are missing.